# .NET 5 API and React UI authentication using Azure AD B2C - Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"

Tags: c#, reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, .net-5

As part of a new project I'm trying to integrate authentication with a React app and a .NET 5 API using Azure AD B2C. I'm almost there, I think, but when making the request I get back a 401 message with "Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid".

- I've registered the API and React app in Azure AD B2C.
- I've given permission to the API from the React app.
- I've created a test scope to start
- I can sign in to my React app and I'm given a bearer token.
- If I inspect the token I can see the audience is my API with the client Id.
- If I make the request, it's passing the token to the API as it should I believe.

In my Startup.cs, I have it defined like so:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"))
```

My test controller endpoint is written as so:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("private")]
public IActionResult Private()
{
    return Ok(new
    {
        Message = "Hello from a private endpoint! You need to be authenticated to see this."
    });
}
```

I have my AzureADB2C settings in my appsettings.json like so:

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "<API Client Id (GUID)>",
    /*
      You need specify the TenantId only if you want to accept access tokens from a single tenant
     (line-of-business app).
      Otherwise, you can leave them set to common.
      This can be:
      - A GUID (Tenant ID = Directory ID)
      - 'common' (any organization and personal accounts)
      - 'organizations' (any organization)
      - 'consumers' (Microsoft personal accounts)
    */
    "TenantId": "common"
  },
```

I'm wrestling with a mixture of out of date documentation in some cases and the examples given use a node.js API with no .NET API examples so I've tried to piece together everything as best I can and I'm not quite sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Net Core Web API with Azure AD B2C, we need to update appsetting.json as below

```
 "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://xxx.b2clogin.com",
    "ClientId": "",
    "Domain": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1A_signup_signin"
  },
```

For more details, please refer to the [blog](https://thecodeblogger.com/2020/05/13/protect-net-core-api-using-azure-ad-b2c-and-msal/), the [blog](https://daniel-krzyczkowski.github.io/Cars-Island-ASP-NET-Core-API-Secured-By-Azure-AD-B2C/) and the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-2-B2C).

Besides, regarding how to integrate Azure AD B2C with react application, please refer to [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-react-samples/b2c-sample).

Comment: Thanks, I've made some changes, looks like I may have been following AzureAD guidance, rather than B2C which won't help. The examples indicate that a TenantId is not required, however if I omit that, the error details say that that is required. If I add it back, the error `IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://<mytenant>.b2clogin.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'` is  given instead.

Comment: Also if I change common to my actual TenantId, I get a 404 which seems odd as I copied it from the Azure portal.